# Why can I not access private members when overloading c++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, operator-overloading

The following is some class declarations for a point and vector

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H
class Point {

    private:
        float x;
        float y;

    public:
        Point();
        Point(float x, float y);
        float get_x() const;
        float get_y() const;
        void set_x(float x);
        void set_y(float y);

};

class Vec : Point {
    
    public:
        Vec(float x, float y, float x1, float y1);
        Vec cross(Vec &v);
        Vec cross(float value);
        Vec dot(Vec& v);
        Vec mag();
        Vec normalize();
        Vec rotate(float w);
        Vec operator+(const Vec& v);
        Vec operator-(const Vec& v);
        Vec operator*(float s);
        Vec operator/(float s);
                    
};

#endif
```

here is me implementing one of the operator overloading functions (for now I am simply calling setting the x value to another value)

```
Vec Vec::operator+(const Vec& v) {
    this->x = 0;
}
```

For some reason I get the following error:

```
    error: ‘float Point::x’ is private within this context
```

even though this function is within the private context.
Can somebody please explain why I cannot do this? I have other functions that are member functions and they don't have this problem. It only happens when I am overloading operators.

Comment: `x` is private member of `Point`, not `Vec`. No function in `Vec` can access it. Did you mean to make those members `protected`?

Comment: That's what `private` means... If you want the derivatives to have access to the 'private' base class members, use `protected`. But that's actually not needed, as `Point` has public getter and setter functions. You should instead use these.

Comment: I think there is a bigger problem here.... Why is `Vec` derived from `Point`? Is `Vec` a sort of `Point`? I don't think so. You probably want `Vec` to *have* a `Point`... or even multiple points... Please rethink your design.

Comment: A `Vec` is-a `Point`?  That's like saying a Car is a Wheel.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie like [this](https://www.tuvie.com/wp-content/uploads/hamster-wheel-futuristic-car-concept.jpg)?

Comment: It is often useful to see a vector as a point. The vector cant have a point, id rather have x and y as members to perform operations on them.

Comment: @JHBonarius Well, that could be the exceptional case.  How about a Car is-a Sparkplug?

Comment: @NoahFletcher then how do you intend to go from `Vec(float x, float y, float x1, float y1);` to `Point(float x, float y);`?

Comment: @Eljay yeah, I noticed that 'error' too. But since the whole design smells (IMHO) I chose not to mention that.

Comment: ok, now I see the private inheritance.

Comment: Saying Vec is a point is nothing like saying a car is a wheel. A vector can literally be a point and is very useful to treat it that way.

Comment: @JHBonarius You can get there by just taking a vector difference.

Comment: That's reversed. A [Euclidean vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector) should be the base concept and a 2-dimensional point could be a specialization of that base.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to enable derivatives to get access to private members of the base class, you can make them `protected`.

**UPDATE:** But beware, you are using private inheritance, when subclassing the `Point` with the `Vec`. If you really want to use Point's public functions as interface, you should use public inheritance. Otherwise only Vec class would be able to use Point functions.

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H
class Point {

    protected:
        float x;
        float y;

    public:
        Point();
        Point(float x, float y);
        float get_x() const;
        float get_y() const;
        void set_x(float x);
        void set_y(float y);

};

// Maybe you should use public inheritance here
class Vec : /*public*/ Point {
    
    public:
        Vec(float x, float y, float x1, float y1);
        Vec cross(Vec &v);
        Vec cross(float value);
        Vec dot(Vec& v);
        Vec mag();
        Vec normalize();
        Vec rotate(float w);
        Vec operator+(const Vec& v);
        Vec operator-(const Vec& v);
        Vec operator*(float s);
        Vec operator/(float s);
                    
};

#endif
```

Comment: Then what's the point of `get_x()` and `set_x()`?

Comment: Maybe that was designed to be an interface that should be common for the base class and the derivatives.

Comment: @Vasilij Spot on. Cheers mate.

Comment: @JHBonarius, point taken, thanks! Updated the answer, mentioned the private inheritance. Noticed it, but didn't pay attention to it the first time. It prohibited to use the base class functions as interface.

Comment: He's happy with this, but it's probably going to be terrible code he's making ;)

Comment: Hard to argue. My logic in such cases is that I focus on the name of the question to help the guys who are just quick googling the same situation. If I emphasize on the refactoring, then the small quick answer to the original question would disappear among all the other staff. Maybe not the the best logic for all cases))) I do hope the OP paid attention to the comments, they are really valuable. SO is great at that - lots of people really trying to help.